# Substituting $x = by$ in a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In my textbook, we have the differential equation (some constants omitted)
$$\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} + (1-x^2)\psi = 0$$

and the author introduces the new variable $y$ which is related to $x$ by 
$$x = by$$

for some $b$ and, feeding the above into the differential equation, we arrive at

$$\frac{d^2 \psi}{dy^2} + b^2 \psi - b^4 y^2 \psi = 0.$$

What exactly are the steps we take when we "feed" $x= by$ into the differential equation? In particular, how is $\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2}$ related to $\frac{d^2 \psi}{dy^2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, you have to apply chain rule. $$ \frac{d\psi}{dy}=\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}=b\frac{d\psi}{dx}$$. Similarly, we can do find out derivative again using the same method and substitute in the above differential equation.